# Uncaught Error: []: "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Are you trying to use a store before calling "app.use(pinia)"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I was trying to access a store in Pinia for my Vue webapp but, even though I have installed Pinia and set `app.use(createPinia())`, I get this error:
`Uncaught Error: []: "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Are you trying to use a store before calling "app.use(pinia)"?`

Here's the sources:

*Vue file:*

```
<script>
import SideUpBar from "@/components/SideUpBar.vue";
import {mapActions, mapState} from "pinia"
import { useUsersStore } from "@/stores/users"

const usersStore = useUsersStore()

export default {
  name: "NewView",
  components: {SideUpBar},
  data: () => ({
    //
  }),
  computed: {
    ...mapState(useUsersStore, ['users']),
  },
  methods: {
    // ...mapActions(useUsersStore, ['fetchUsers']),
  },
  created() {
    usersStore.fetchUsers()
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <v-layout class="dim">
    <SideUpBar/>
    <v-main style="background: #C19A6B">
      <v-list
        :items="users"
        item-title="username"
      ></v-list>
    </v-main>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<style>
.dim {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
</style>
```

*main.js:*

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import {createPinia, setActivePinia} from 'pinia'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

// Vuetify
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import  * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import  * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

const vuetify= createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
})

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)
app.use(vuetify)

app.mount('#app')
```

*users.js (store):*

```
import {defineStore} from "pinia"

import axios from "axios"
import {ca} from "vuetify/locale";

export const useUsersStore = defineStore("user", {
    state: () => ({
        users: [],
    }),
    actions: {
        async fetchUsers() {
            try {
                const data = await axios.get('api/users')
                let users = data.data.data
                this.users = users
                console.log(data)
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e)
                console.log(e)
            }
        },
    },
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of wrapping a store in `useUsersStore` composable is to avoid early instantiation and related race conditions. Composables are generally supposed to be called in the body of component setup and contemporary lifecycle hooks (`data`, `created`, etc), any other usage depends on the implementation of a composable. Pinia composables don't have this restriction but calling them earlier than that prevents them from working.

The problem is that `useUsersStore` is called at the top level of the module. With options API, it should be either:

```
  created() {
    useUsersStore().fetchUsers()
  },
  ...
```

Or:

```
  data: () => ({
    usersStore: useUsersStore()
  }),
  created() {
    this.usersStore.fetchUsers()
  },
  ...
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and now it works, thanks! I discovered that it can be also resolved by implementig the lazy load of the routes, but I will use your solution. :)